# Target/Source and owning/not owning entities

Tags: jpa, orm

I'm a bit confused about this naming convention. 
What is the difference between them and are target/source interchangeable with owning/not owning?

One thing in particular is hard to understand:

*"The main difference between a OneToOne and a ManyToOne relationship in JPA is that a ManyToOne always contains a foreign key from the source object's table to the target object's table, where as a **OneToOne relationship the foreign key may either be in the source object's table or the target object's table**"*

JPA wikibooks

I can't imagine such situation in uni one-to-one

Comment: This is an interesting question but sadly still without an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Differences between them are a little confusing. You should practice a lot to understand very well.

At first, you should understand some terminology:

**Role** : In every relationship there are two entities that are related to one another, and each entity is said to play a role in the relationship.

**Direction** : Relationships can be unidirectional or bidirectional. For e.g.. a Person has an address is normally unidirectional whereas Employee working on a project is normally bidirectional. We will look at how to identify and define directionality while coming up with a Data Model.

In order to have relationships at all, there has to be a way to create, remove, and maintain them. The basic way this is done is by an entity having a relationship attribute that refers to its related entity in a way that identifies it as playing the other role of the relationship. It is often the case that the other entity, in turn, has an attribute that points back to the original entity. When each entity points to the other, the relationship is bidirectional. If only one entity has a pointer to the other, the relationship is said to be unidirectional. A relationship from an Employee to the Project that they work on would be bidirectional. The Employee should know its Project, and the Project should point to the Employee working on it. A UML model of this relationship is shown here. The arrows going in both directions indicate the bidirectionality of the relationship (Form this book >> [Pro JPA 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219564))

[image]

Then dive into this [link (archived from the original)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140305170822/http://www.kumaranuj.com/2013/05/jpa-2-understanding-relationships.html)

I'd like to comment only the links, but I need 50 reputation